# How to centre thumbnails in div with overflow hidden?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of thumbnails that are all varying sizes. The divs they sit in are all set at 50px x 50px, with the overflow: hidden. I want to centre and vertically align the images within the 50px x 50px divs so that the little bit of image that is visible is mostly the centre of the images. The reason I need to do this is that on the website I am making there are a lot of these small thumbnails, and some are landscape, some portrait, therefore the size of the images themselves have to be set at a bigger width than the width of the divs.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/6trNw/

```
.thumbnail-wrapper {
height: 50px;
margin: 7px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 50px;
}
.thumbnail-wrapper img {
width: 95px;
}



<div class="thumbnails">

<div class="thumbnail-wrapper"><img  src="http://intelligen.info/images/Commercial%3ACommissions%3AClients/Poplin/-2.jpeg "alt="yoga 1"></div>
<div class="thumbnail-wrapper"><img src="http://intelligen.info/images/Commercial%3ACommissions%3AClients/Poplin/-3.jpeg" alt="Poplin 2 "alt="yoga 2"></div>
<div class="thumbnail-wrapper"><img src="http://intelligen.info/images/Commercial%3ACommissions%3AClients/Poplin/-4.jpeg" alt="Poplin 3 "alt="yoga 3"></div>
<div class="thumbnail-wrapper"><img src="http://intelligen.info/images/Commercial%3ACommissions%3AClients/yoga/Screen Shot 2014-05-01 at 10.08.10.png" alt="yoga 4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing your markup, as I see that you have specified a ***fixed size*** to both the container `div`s and the `img`s, you absolutely the position the images using a little percentage calculation on the size.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6trNw/1/***

```
.thumbnail-wrapper {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.thumbnail-wrapper img {
    width: 95px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40%; left: -40%;
}
```

If, your size is *not fixed*, then the best bet is to use images as `background-image` as answered by SW4.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way would be to leverage off `background-size:cover` and `background-position:center center;` CSS, although this would mean moving your images directly to the background of your `divs` it will flexibly give you the functionality you want.

nb. I've left the image locations inline- you can move these to your CSS if you require, but in this instance i'd leave 'as-is'

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/6trNw/6/)

Why not change your HTML to:

```
<div class="thumbnails">
    <div class="thumbnail-wrapper" style='background-image:url(http://intelligen.info/images/Commercial%3ACommissions%3AClients/Poplin/-2.jpeg);'></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-wrapper" style='background-image:url(http://intelligen.info/images/Commercial%3ACommissions%3AClients/Poplin/-3.jpeg);'></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-wrapper" style='background-image:url(http://intelligen.info/images/Commercial%3ACommissions%3AClients/Poplin/-4.jpeg);'></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-wrapper" style='background-image:url(http://intelligen.info/images/Commercial%3ACommissions%3AClients/yoga/Screen Shot 2014-05-01 at 10.08.10.png);'></div>
</div>
```

Then use the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: gray;
}
.thumbnail-wrapper {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 7px;
    width: 50px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same. If you want to avoid `overflow:hidden;` then you can't really place an image inside an element and expert it to hide the overflowing parts.

Comment: Thanks but I can't change my html so i will use the method of positioning and percentage setting to move the images inside the divs.